# Convertapi Word2PDF in Java

Tags: groovy, convertapi

I'm having problems reading the response from the server. If I use the StoreFile parameter and access via URL the PDF looks great, but serving it up through my own server always renders the pages blank. Possibly an encoding issue?

```
def convertPdf(document) {
    File f = new File(document)
    RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
    def resp = rest.post("https://do.convertapi.com/Word2Pdf") {
        contentType "multipart/form-data"
        ApiKey = "CONFIDENTIAL"
        file = f
    }
    InputStream istream = new ByteArrayInputStream(resp.getBody().getBytes());
    File file = new File("123123.pdf");
    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int num = 0;
    while ((num = istream.read(b)) != -1) {
        ostream.write(b, 0, num);
    }
    istream.close();
    ostream.flush();
    ostream.close();
}
```

Comment: This is, at *best*, Groovy.  Java doesn't use `def` anywhere.

Comment: Yes, Groovy, sorry. Java solutions would work here though. Why 'at best'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by using the method on "mashape" and using their Unirest library.

```
def downloadPdf() {
    HttpResponse<InputStream> response = Unirest.post("https://do.convertapi.com/Word2Pdf")
    .field("ApiKey", "CONFIDENTIAL")
    .field("File", new File(params.document))
    .field("OutputFormat", "pdf")
    .field("Timeout", 300)
    .field("OutputFileName", params.fileName)
    .asBinary();
    render(file: response.getBody(), contentType: "application/octet-stream", fileName: params.fileName+".pdf")
}
```